# Comprehensive list of command line flags/options for Burn/bootstrapper in WiX

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I can't seem to find a *comprehensive* list of commands, flags, and things I can do from the command line.

Comment: As a person in the top 10% of answerers for the `WiX` tag, I agree that this is not something easily found via google search unless you are already familiar with WiX/MSI terminology.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

WiX installers will take the standard Windows Installer commandline switches, as documented in *[Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options)*.

Any additional parameters that are added to the commandline will be passed on to your installer if you're using a custom Burn installer.

This was confirmed by the primary WiX maintainer on the WiX mailing list: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-tp5913001p5913628.html

> 1. Yes, absolutely. Burn supports parsing the "standard package switches"  and will pass extra switches on the Bootstrapper
>    Application so it can apply  additional behavior.
> 2. The complete list is dependent on the Bootstrapper Application you pick.  The wixstdba supports only the "standard package switches":

```
 -q, -quiet, -s, -silent = silent install
 -passive = progress bar only install
 -norestart = suppress any restarts
 -forcerestart = restart no matter what (I don't know why this is still  around)
 -promptrestart = prompt if a restart is required (default)
 -layout = create a local image of the bootstrapper (i.e. download files so  they can be burned to DVD)
 -l, -log = log to a specific file (default is controled by bundle developer)
 -uninstall = uninstall
 -repair = repair (or install if not installed)
 -package,-update = install (default if no -uninstall or -repair)
```

> 3. Yes, as noted above extra command-line parameters are passed to the >  BootstrapperApplication and it can set Variables to flow into Chained  Packages (ExePackage XxxCommand attributes or
>    MsiPackage/MsiProperty  element).

You may want to also be familiar with the standard installer command line parameters: *[Microsoft Standard Installer Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options)*

Comment: @bob, if this answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as the answer.  If it didn't, let me know what's missing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you -- yes, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: How to display a custom message for the user action, based on these command-line parameters - for a pending restart? Can It be done in the middle of the installation? Or will it be only accounted for at the end of installation (using custom BA)?

Comment: @ArNumb that's not something done with commandline parameters. If you want customized behavior, that would need to be added as part of building the installer,

Comment: @JohnM.Wright : I have some idea doing that...was reading your blog too. I know this isn't the appropriate way of asking, but if possible, please redirect me to any link/guide to achieve this...

Comment: The second link is broken - *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com."*