# msiexec override command line logging

Tags: windows-installer

I have some msi applications that are installed using a exe wrapper the exe wrapper appears to be passing in msiexec /i (msifile) /L(some logging path and options) is there a way to override these logging option so that it logs to the default location of C:\windows\temp and produce a full voicewarmupx log.

I've tried setting DisableLoggingFromPackage to 1 in the registry but doesn't see to have any effect.

DisableLoggingFromPackage = 1

I want to receive a full verbose log in the default logging location.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Summary***: The below basically relates to the following, potential options:
>
> 1. Combine several **`logging policies`** (not positive this will work).
> 2. Extract MSI from **`setup.exe`** and use your own command line for each MSI in sequence.

---

### 1. Logging

***Logging Policies***: Apologies if this is done already, just have to make sure: you might want to enable the global logging policy (unless it is done already) in combination with the **`DisableLoggingFromPackage`** and then reboot?:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
"Logging"="voicewarmup"
"Debug"=dword:00000007
"DisableLoggingFromPackage"=dword:00000001
```

With the global logging policy enabled you don't need to repeat logging commands for all packages, and the **`DisableLoggingFromPackage`** policy added as well should make it work for all packages.

***More on Logging***: Recommended answer on logging in general:

> - **[Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)**
> - [**List of `setup.exe` switches for Burn Bundles**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332496/comprehensive-list-of-command-line-flags-options-for-burn-bootstrapper-in-wix/44347702#44347702)

---

After enabling the policy, please check both the 64-bit and 32-bit registry locations:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer
```

I believe these locations are pointing to the same registry data, so there should be no discrepancies between them. Please just check.

Also check for any policy entries in HKCU (if that is even possible - I don't think it is, there are fewer per-user policies).

---

### 2. MSI Extraction

***Extract***: Can you extract the MSI files from the **`setup.exe`** and run them in sequence instead - with the exact command line of your choosing? I would do so - especially if you are using a distribution system and you are in a corporate environment.

***Sidenote***: There are many different **`setup.exe`** types, each with their own way to extract files. Here is an answer on this issue: [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512).

***WiX Bundle Extraction***: Extracting the content from a WiX **`setup.exe`** bundle is not entirely straightforward since you need the [WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) installed (unless this has changed recently). Download it and install it first. Here is a: [WiX quick-start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) - just for the record, but all you need is this command:

```
"%WIX%bin\dark.exe" -x outputfolder setup.exe
```

[More on dark here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (in section 4). You should get all embedded content extracted to **`"outputfolder"`**. Take it from there. Many embedded setups could be standard runtimes (**`Java`**, **`VC++ runtimes`**, **`.NET framework`**, **`etc...`** - stuff you rarely need to deploy to a managed, corporate system - it is already there).

---

***Links***:

- https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/50
- [**Different ways to create and interpret MSI logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).